# dropdown with option to add new element

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Is it possible to have a dropdown control with functionality that if there is no element in the dropdown im interested in I can just type it in myself ?

thanks for any help

Comment: Yes, it's possible... did you have a specific question? (Lets start with: Do you use any js framework like jQuery?)

Comment: Do you want to add the dropdown element programmatically from JavaScript or via asp.net logic?

Comment: are you populate the elements from database?

Comment: Please give some code because the jquery solutions won't work in an asp.net context due to viewstate and asp.net postback handling

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I know this question hasn't been tagged `jQuery`, but for future users searching i'll provide a start for a jquery solution.

---

Here's a relly simple start to a jQuery plugin to handle allowing dynamic options into a select box. An extra textbox and button is added to the DOM for each select element. Also an option is added to the bottom of the select list with text such as "add item...". Selected this option allows the user to type a new item in and add it to the select box.

Live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/8G6z3/1/

```
(function($) {


    $.fn.freeEntry= function(options){

        var settings = $.extend(
             {},
             {  //defaults
                 addItemText: 'add item...'
             },
             options
          );

        return this.each(function(){

            var $this = $(this);

            var $addItemOption = $('<option>' + settings.addItemText + '</option>');
            $this.append($addItemOption);

            var $addItemControl = $('<input type=text>').hide();
            $addItemControl.insertAfter($this);
            var $addItemButton = $('<input type=button value="add">').hide();
            $addItemButton.insertAfter($addItemControl);
            $addItemButton.click(function(){
                if($addItemControl.val().length){
                     var $newOption = $('<option>' + $addItemControl.val() + '</option>');  
                    $newOption.insertBefore('option:last',$this)
                    $this.val($addItemControl.val());
                    $addItemControl.val('');                
                }
                $addItemControl.hide();
                $addItemButton.hide();
            });

            $this.change(function(){
               var $this = $(this);
                if($this.val() == settings.addItemText){
                     $addItemControl.show().focus();
                    $addItemButton.show();
                }
            });
        });
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Usage: `$('#mySelectBox').freeEntry( { addItemText: "Add a new item yo!"} );`

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the standard HTML `select` control, however you could use an HTML `input` textbox, which uses AJAX autocomplete to display a dropdown:

http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/

---

Alternatively, you could have an "Other" option in the HTML `select` dropdown, which when selected, will display a `TextBox` control

Answer (score 0):

You could have a text box near the drop down list with a submit button which appends html  to the list section?